# How to remove a single email address from echo output?

Tags: php

I just want to remove an email address from my script output.  I have searched everywhere and nothing seems relevant to my script.  For example, how would I remove user@domain.com from the echoed output?

```
<?
$dat = file_get_contents('webhook.dat');
$dat .= "\n" . file_get_contents('webhook1.dat');
$dat .= "\n" . file_get_contents('webhook2.dat');
$fp = fopen('webhookmerge.dat', 'w');
if(!$fp)
  die('Could not create / open data file for writing.');
if(fwrite($fp, $dat) === false)
  die('Could not write to data file.'); 
?>

<?
$file = "webhookmerge.dat";
$text=file_get_contents($file);
$res = preg_match_all(
  "/[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/i",
  $text, $matches);
sort($matches[0]);
if ($res) {
  foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
    echo "<b><font color='black' face='arial' size='2pt'>$email</font></b>" . "<br />";
  }
}
else {
  echo "No emails found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see where user@domain is in you output now. Can you be more specific about where this is being about and what you have tried to do to solve this problem?

Comment: The output is in the browser when I run the script by going to the script address in my server.  This script collects all the email addresses from 3 .dat files.  The problem I have is that there is an email address in the output that I don't want to be there.  How do I filter out the unwanted email address using my script?  What line of code do I need to add?

Comment: can you properly indent your code, so it's easier for people you're asking help of to read it? Also `<font>` does not exist. It used to exist in HTML 3.2, but hasn't existed since HTML 4.01, which was released well over 10 years ago. Similarly, `<b>` is typically `<strong>`, and any styling you need you do through CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid printing of some strings you can add check before `echo` command:

```
foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $email) {
  if ($email != "user@domain.com") {
    echo "<b><font color='black' face='arial' size='2pt'>$email</font></b><br />";
  }
}
```